# Where should I start background threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm writing a windows form application in c# which should have a couple of threads which do some work in background, and which should terminate only when the application is closed. The problem is that if do this:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            r = new Reader();

            Thread readThread = new Thread(r.Do);

            readThread.Start();

            while (!readThread.IsAlive) ;

        }
```

and I check with the debugger it looks like the "Do" method is executed only once. Am I starting the thread from the correct position in the code? Am I doing some other error?

Comment: Well you only started one thread..?

Comment: Whats happening here is, your Do method is started on another thread. When you start the thread, it will execute the Do method(ones). When the Do method exits. You thread is stopped(not alive anymore). If you want a thread that stays alive, you should create a loop into it

Comment: Turns out it was a very very stupid mistake:

at the begin of the Do method, instead of having:

    while (!_shouldStop)

I had

    if (!_shouldStop)

I'm embarassed...

Comment: btw, smarter move would be to put whole threading inside class `Reader` and call r.Start() from "outside".  Encapsulation, yada-yada..

Comment: A best practice (for me) is using ManualResetEvent on the while loops.  These are threadsafe and easy to use:    Creation: ManualResetEvent terminated = new ManualResetEvent(false);     Within thread: while(terminated.WaitOne(0)) { };      When terminating: terminated.Set();

Comment: And in addition to Daniel Mošmondor, something like a Dispose method of the Reader class should be responsible for terminating the thread.

Comment: Why not use `Task` instead of `Thread`? Or a few `BackgroundWorker` classes?